# Not able to update product Record in MongoDB from Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi My User Model contains 4 Fields id name description status not able to update record through node in Mongo DB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52YRE.png)

Comment: Could you add a bit more details about your issue? It is very hard to help you here, because we do not know how the users are built or even which error message is being shown (if any).

Comment: xports.updateProduct = function (id, product) {
    console.log("Update Product in Index1 Start", id, product);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        collection.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: monk.id(id) }, { $set: product }).then(data => {
            console.log("Data", data);
            resolve(data);
        }, err => {
            console.log("Error Update in Index1", err);
            reject("Update User Failed");
        });
    });
}